# Are projections separated and of finite type?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Premise: Let $\pi :X\to Y$ be a projection between varieties in projective complex space in the sense that $X\subseteq \mathbb P^n\times \mathbb P^m$, $Y\subseteq \mathbb P^m$ and $\pi(x_1,x_2)=x_2$.

Question: Viewing this map as a morphism of schemes, is it always separated and of finite type? I'm not very familiar with the language of schemes, so I would appreciate some help.

Definition: A morphism is *separated* if the image of the diagonal map $\Delta:X\to X\times_Y X$ is closed (this seems intuitively obvious in this case.) The definition of *finite type* I use is from Wikipedia.

Comment: Once you know $\mathbb P^n\to pt$ satisfies these properties, since both these properties are stable under base change, the projection $\mathbb P^n\times\mathbb P^m\to\mathbb P^m$ also satisfies the properties.

Comment: And both properties are preserved under restriction of the map to $X$?

Comment: The class of separated morphisms of finite type is also closed under composition. So it is enough to know that the inclusion $X \to \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m$ is also separated and of finite type – and in fact it is.

Comment: By the way, please use [markdown formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format text that's not a math expression - for instance, you can get *italics* by typing `*italics*`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true. In detail:

Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ be two morphisms of schemes. We say a property $\mathcal{P}$ of morphisms of schemes satisfies cancellation iff $g\circ f$ has $\mathcal{P}$ implies $f$ has $\mathcal{P}$. Separated morphisms satisfy cancellation (ref [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01KV) ) and morphisms locally of finite type over a base satisfy cancellation (ref [Stacks 01T8](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01T8)). (For locally of finite type, the statement is that if $X\to S$ is an $S$-scheme locally of finite type and $Y\to S$ is an $S$-scheme, then any $S$-map $X\to Y$ is again locally of finite type.)

We also know that any morphism out of a noetherian scheme is quasi-compact, and any scheme of finite type over a noetherian base is again noetherian. So it suffices to show that $X$ is separated and finite type over $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C$ in order to conclude that any $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C$-morphism out of $X$ is separated and of finite type.

This is a consequence of the fact that $X$ is projective over $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C$: the closed immersion $X\to\Bbb P^n$ and the structure map $\Bbb P^n\to\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C$ are both proper, so their composition is, and as proper is finite type + separated + universally closed, we're done.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything special about the projection morphism, or is for instance any morphism between projective algebraic sets separated and of finite type?

Comment: As per the last sentence in the third paragraph, any morphism out of a separated finite type scheme over a field $k$ to another $k$-scheme is separated and of finite type. In particular, that implies the claim you ask about in the comment. (Sorry for leaving this for a couple days, I lost the notification.)